# Sql Azure Monitoring tool

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'd like to collect information about top N queries ranked by execution time. The same as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394114.aspx. But I need historical data. Is there any tool for this? Something really simple and cheap. Or it is better to implement this by myself? Like it is described here: http://wasa.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a paid service to do this monitoring, [Cotega](http://www.cotega.com) may be an options for you.  We do monitoring and store historical data on your SQL Azure database.  We actually previously logged top N queries, but stopped doing it as it was hard for DBA's to use this information.  It would be great to hear more about how you would like to see and use this information as it would be pretty easy to add this capability back in.

If you want to do this yourself, there are some great services such as Aditi that can be used to schedule processes that would allow you to create some code to be executed on regular basis to log this yourself.

Full disclosure, I work on the Cotega service.

Comment: Hi. The purpose is simple. To find out the queries which causes performance degradation. Current snapshot is not very useful because it doesn't reflect whole situation. I'd like to have at least one day history. I already checked (and registered) Cotega before asking the question. Pricing is really good. But as you said there is no historical data about queries performance. So now I'm planning to implement it by myself.